# Prove symmetry of natural logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, symmetry

> Prove that $f(x)=\ln\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is symmetrical in $x=0$.

$\ln\sqrt{(x-a)^2+1}=\ln\sqrt{(x+a)^2+1}$

$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+1}=\sqrt{(x+a)^2+1}$

$(x-a)^2+1=(x+a)^2+1$

$x^2-2ax+a^2+1=x^2+2ax+a^2+1$

$-2ax=2ax$

$-x=x$?

I don't know what to do? Is this the proof or did I miss something?

Comment: Don't you just have to show that $f(-x)=f(x)$, which is easy because of the $x^2$?

Comment: The symmetry about $0$ comes from $x^2$ being an even function, not from $\log$.

Comment: The $a$ stuff is not useful for the problem. And in general $\ln((x-a)^2+1)\ne \ln((x+a)^2+1)$.

Comment: Thanks Nishant and André! ;-)

Comment: @user3761304: See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can prove that your function is an even function that is

> $$ f(-x)=f(x) $$

then it is symmetrical about the $y$-axis or the line $x=0$. In your case we have

> $$ f(-x) = \ln(\sqrt{(-x)^2+1}) = \ln(\sqrt{(x)^2+1}) = f(x) $$

which proves the symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is symmetrical about a line $x=a$ then it can be said that:
$$f(x)=f(2a-x)\forall x\in\mathbb R$$
$$\ln\sqrt{x^2+1}=\ln\sqrt{(2a-x)^2+1}$$
By using property $\ln a^b=b\ln a$
$$\ln(x^2+1)=\ln((2a-x)^2+1)$$
Since "$\ln$" is a one-one function:
$$x^2=(2a-x)^2$$
Expanding and cancelling:
$$4a^2=4ax$$
It gives two solutions:
$$a=0,x=a$$
Since we want symmetry for all real points we take the solution line $x=a(=0)$

**For this question there was an easy way:**
You could just have shown that $$x^2=(-x)^2$$ and the rest follows after.